# ASP.NET webforms problem --- dropdownlist is not holding the value after selecting item

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, dropdown

I have 3 drop downs, the first dropdown' product dropdown '  populates the second dropdown 'category dropdown' based on the selected item and the second dropdown populates the third dropdown ' part dropdown' based on the selected value, but the issue is whenever I select the item from the second dropdown it perfectly populates the third dropdown i.e part dropdown but it does not hold its own selected item and also second dropdown changes itself to third dropdown i.e part dropdown. It means after selecting the item from the second dropdown total number of parts dropdown becomes two.

product dropdown

```
<asp:DropDownList id="slctproduct" runat="server" name="select" class="form-control form- 
control-primary"  onchange="selectcategory(); return false;"> </asp:DropDownList>
```

category dropdown

```
<asp:DropDownList id="slctpartcategory" runat="server" class="form-control form-control- 
 primary" onchange="selectpart(); return false;" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

part dropdown

```
 <asp:DropDownList id="slctpart" runat="server" name="select" class="form-control form 
 control-primary" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

code to populate category dropdown based on the selected item of the product dropdown

```js
function selectcategory() {
    var product = document.getElementById('<%= slctproduct.ClientID %>');
    // Fetch and populate part categories based on the selected product
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "RNI_Agent_PartStockReport.aspx/RNI_Fetch_PartCategoryForCN",
        data: "{ 'P': { 'RNI_FK_CN_PartCategory': '" + product.value + "' } }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            var ddlProducts2 = $("[id*=slctpartcategory]");
            ddlProducts2.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="-1">Select Part Category</option>');
            $.each(r.d, function () {
                ddlProducts2.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
            });
        }
    }); 
}
```

below code is written in code behind the file (aspx.cs)

```
public static List<ListItem> RNI_Fetch_PartCategoryForCN(Properties P)
{
    using (cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        List<ListItem> type = new List<ListItem>();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_Fetch_PartcategoryForCN";
        cmd.Connection = Getconnected.getconnecting();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product", P.RNI_FK_CN_PartCategory);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", P.RNI_FK_SelectedPartCategory); 
        using (sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (sdr.Read())
            {

                type.Add(new ListItem
                {

                    Value = sdr[0].ToString(),
                    Text = sdr[1].ToString()
                });
            }
        }

        return type;
    }
}
```

code to populate part dropdown based on the selected item of the category dropdown

```js
    function selectpart() {


        var partcategory = document.getElementById('<%= slctpartcategory.ClientID %>');
       
        // Check if any of the inputs are empty or null

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "RNI_Agent_PartStockReport.aspx/RNI_Fetch_Part",
            data: "{ 'P': { 'FK_Part': '" + partcategory.value + "' } }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                var ddlProducts = $("[id*=slctpart]");
                ddlProducts.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="-1">Select Part</option>');
                $.each(r.d, function () {
                    ddlProducts.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                });    
            }
        });
    }
```

below code is written in code behind the file (aspx.cs)

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<ListItem> RNI_Fetch_Part(Properties P)
{
    using (cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        List<ListItem> type = new List<ListItem>();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_Fetch_PartsfromCategory";
        cmd.Connection = Getconnected.getconnecting();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", P.FK_Part);
        using (sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (sdr.Read())
            {

                type.Add(new ListItem
                {

                    Value = sdr[0].ToString(),
                    Text = sdr[1].ToString()
                });
            }
        }

        return type;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember, on any post-back, the page load event fires BEFORE your code stub(s). So, if you have code in page load that fills out the combo box, then the user's choice will be over written WHEN re-binding ANY of the 3 combo boxes.

What this means is that you can't re-bind the combo box, since doing so will lose the current choice. In most cases, this would be in fact desired behaviour, since if user changes combo 2, then combo 3 would cascade, and the "act" of re-binding combo 3 would also mean that combo 3 loses the current choice (and it should anyway).

Same goes for combo 1 choice, it has to now cascade combo 2, (choice is lost), and you probably should blow out (clear) the combo 3 choice and data source when this occurs.

So, on the "real" and "first" page load, you would fill out combo 1, and combo 2, 3 would be empty.

Now, the above of course assumes server-side code, auto post back.

However, with the introduction of a web method, then some caution will arise, since there is no view state for the combo box, and no post-back.

However, as long as you NOT re-loading the data source for an existing combo box, you should be fine. So, a change in combo 2 should then not only re-load combo 3, but also of course clear the combo 3 choice before that re-load (cascade) of combo 3.

So, check your page load event. You near ALWAYS ALWAYS need to place the first combo 1 load code inside of that all important !IsPostBack code stub.

e.g., this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        string strSQL =
            @"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";

        cboHotels.DataSource = General.MyRst(strSQL);
        cboHotels.DataBind();
        cboHotels.Items.Insert(0, "Select Hotel");

    }
```

So, you don't show your page load event, but keep in mind without a !IsPostBack code stub, then on ANY post-back, if code exists that re-loads a combo box in page load, it will lose the current choice of that combo box. However, with the !IsPostBack code stub, then we don't care that page load event fires on any page post-back, since we only ever run that code on the "real" first page load.

Also, you could dump the ajax, and place the 3 combos’ inside of an update panel. However, no question, extra effort and using ajax to fill out the combo's is a better road to take, but that comes with a lot of extra work compared to 100% server-side code.

So, say we want to cascade 4 combo boxes.

So, Region, then Country, then State, then Cities.

So, this markup:

```
<div style="float:left">
<h4>Region</h4>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboRegion" runat="server"
        DataTextField="Region"
        AutoPostBack="true"
        onchange="GetData(this.value,'GetCountry','cboCountry','');return false"
        Width="150px" >
    </asp:DropDownList>

</div>

<div style="float:left;margin-left:25px">
<h4>Country</h4>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCountry" runat="server" 
        DataTextField="Country" 
        onchange="GetData(this.value,'GetStates','cboState','');return false"
        Width="250px"  >
        
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>

<div style="float:left;margin-left:25px">
<h4>State</h4>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboState" runat="server" 
        DataTextField="state" 
        onchange="GetData(this.value,'GetCity','cboCity',$('#cboCountry').val());return false"
        Width="200px" >
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>

<div style="float:left;margin-left:25px">
<h4>City</h4>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCity" runat="server" 
        DataTextField="city"
        Width="200px"  >
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

And the jQuery ajax routine:

```
<script>
    function GetData(sValue,sMethod, sControl, p2) {

        var ctl = $('#' + sControl)
        var sURL = "CountryCascade.aspx/" + sMethod
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: sURL,
            data: JSON.stringify({p : sValue, p2 : p2 }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                ctl.empty()
                $.each(r.d, function () {
                    ctl.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

So, first combo can be loaded from code behind (don't forget the !IsPostBack stub!!!).

So, then this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        SqlCommand cmdSQL =
            new SqlCommand("SELECT region from vRegion ORDER BY region");
        DataTable rstData;
        rstData = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        cboRegion.DataSource = rstData;
        cboRegion.DataBind();
        cboRegion.Items.Insert(0,"Select Region");
    }
```

Then the web methods:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static List<ListItem> GetCountry(string p, string p2)
{
    string strSQL =
        @"SELECT Country FROM vCountryRegion
        WHERE region = @region
        ORDER BY Country";
    SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@region", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = p;
    DataTable rstData = MyRstP(cmdSQL);

    List<ListItem> sReturn = new List<ListItem>();
    sReturn.Add(new ListItem("Select Country"));
    foreach (DataRow OneRow in rstData.Rows)
        sReturn.Add(new ListItem(OneRow["Country"].ToString()));

    return sReturn;
}
[WebMethod]
public static List<ListItem> GetStates(string p, string p2)
{
    string strSQL =
        @"SELECT state from vCountryStates
                WHERE Country = @Country
                ORDER BY state";
    SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Country", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = p;
    DataTable rstData = MyRstP(cmdSQL);

    List<ListItem> sReturn = new List<ListItem>();
    sReturn.Add(new ListItem("Select State"));
    foreach (DataRow OneRow in rstData.Rows)
        sReturn.Add(new ListItem(OneRow["state"].ToString()));

    return sReturn;
}


[WebMethod]
public static List<ListItem> GetCity(string p, string p2)
{
    string strSQL =
        @"SELECT city from vCities
                WHERE Country_name = @Country
                AND state_name = @State
                ORDER BY city";

    SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@State", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = p;
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Country", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = p2;
    DataTable rstData = MyRstP(cmdSQL);

    List<ListItem> sReturn = new List<ListItem>();
    sReturn.Add(new ListItem("Select City"));
    foreach (DataRow OneRow in rstData.Rows)
        sReturn.Add(new ListItem(OneRow["city"].ToString()));

    return sReturn;
}
```

And the result is this:

[image]

So, at no point in time do I see your issue.

Note that you do want to add a "clear" items before filling out a combo, since the combo may have previous values.

As above shows, of course any child combo will be cleared out, re-filled and the choice is lost since the current selected value may well not exist anymore. So, for any "cascade", the combo needs to be cleared out.

I don't see any selections being lost in above, and as noted, this suggests some post-back is occurring here when you don't want as such.

HOWEVER!

You do have to save + grab the values in the combo boxes BEFORE ANY post-back occurs!
Why?
Well, you are filling out combo boxes with client-side code. As a result, there is no viewstate to save/know/enjoy/use the combo boxes filled out with client-side code.

I find the simplest solution is to move the current select value of the combo box out to a hidden field.

So, while I don't lose the value(s) of any combo box in above? One WILL lose the value(s) of those combo boxes on post-back due to them having no viewstate set by the server. So, in above, the 1st combo box will work fine, and retain its value on post back. The additional combos filled out with client-side code select values will lose their value on postback.

Last but not least?

I used a helper routine in code behind, since it rather tiresome to type connection's string code and a data table pull code over and over. So, this code was used:

```
    public static DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.Countries))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```